# Как найти основной цвет изображения?

Tags: canvas, изображения, html5

Можно ли с помощью `Canvas` определить основной, оттенок (цвет) изображения?

Comment: да, конечно, просто найди среднее арифметическое r, g, b всех пикселей изображения.

Comment: Может быть лучше, все же, не среднее по картинке, а наиболее часто встречающийся цвет? Взять картинку квантизовать-распихать цвета по бинам и посмотреть чего больше всего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно просто готовое решение, то попробуйте вот это: https://github.com/lokesh/color-thief

Все сведется к чему-то такому:

```
var myImage = $('#myImage');
var dominantColor = getDominantColor(myImage);
```